# What Virtual Machine (virtualization) solution to use?

Tags: macos, mac, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Virtualization software for a Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/106918/virtualization-software-for-a-mac)

I am a Mac user and wanted to have Windows 7 as a Virtual Machine. I know about only two possible solutions/software that I can install on Mac

1. VirtualBox
2. VMWare Fusion (not free)

I am not sure which one to install. My needs are:

1. It should be free
2. It should be available for Macs

Comment: How can you be unsure when one of them meets your needs and one of them does not meet your needs?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/106918/virtualization-software-for-a-mac
Related: http://superuser.com/questions/52700/boot-camp-parallels-virtualbox-or-fusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VMware fusion is a more advanced product, but you may not need its features. Fusion has the ability to integrate with the host OS more smoothly, and to run Aero in a VM. VirtualBox can integrate into the host OS, but is less graceful. VirtualBox also has accelerated graphics (beta), but because their drivers are not signed by Microsoft, it will not run Aero. If you just need to run a few applications in Windows every once in a while, there's no point in paying for VMware Fusion, but if you'll be doing extensive work in Windows, then it might be worth the cost.

Answer (score 4):

If you want it to be free, and VMWare is not free, then you should probably go with the free solution: [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/). Parallels is another not-free solution that you should not consider.

Comment: LOL@"Parallels is another not-free solution that you should not consider" xD

Answer (score 3):

VMware Fusion is probably the best Virtualization software I have used on a Mac, I would use it mainly if I want to use it's Unity mode to integrate the Guest OS with the Host since it does it much better than VirtualBox.

If you just want an environment to test out different OS's then go for VirtualBox.